# 2003 Nissan Maxima vibrating

Tags: nissan, manual-transmission, vibration, maxima

[My 2003 Nissan Maxima, with standard transmission, is vibrating a lot.]

I have changed the motor mounts, ignition coil packs, clutch, and my car still vibrates.  A lot.

Does anyone know what the cause is?

When I press the clutch at any speed I will feel the vibration, and when it is at idle it is more intense.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do the RPMs dip or fluctuate a lot at idle?

Comment: No, there is no dip in RMPs and no fluctuating at idle.   It only has a vibration. The vibrate increases when I hold the clutch down , that is at high speeds (50-60 mph).  Then the vibration is noticeable while at a complete stop.  While accelerating there seems to be no vibration.        Thank you.

Comment: Does it seem like the vibration is coming from any place in particular?